# "String cannot be converted to CharSequence" all over the place in a Java project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I reopen a project which was compiling and running fine, and I get errors:

> "String cannot be converted to CharSequence"

on all lines that involve String operations, like:

```
String status = "blah blah";
int countArobase = StringUtils.countMatches(status, "@");
// error "String cannot be converted to CharSequence" at the "@" String.
```

**Note**: `StringUtils` comes from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`

Same error with native methods, like:

```
String feature;
boolean test = feature.contains("blah blah");
// error "String cannot be converted to CharSequence" at the "blah blah" String.
```

It is so strange that I'd almost suspect a problem with the IDE? (I use NetBeans 8.0.2)

Comment: Ok I just checked, does not happen with NetBeans 8.1. Strange.

Comment: Nice to know my former Coursera instructor has the same problems I do! Now I only wish we had the same solution. I was already using 8.1. I think this is why only 5% of Java developers use Netbeans. I'm going back to Eclipse.

Comment: :-) It occurred just once in the 5 years I have been using NetBeans. Nothing to complain about NetBeans, I love the stability of the IDE!

Comment: Yes, Netbeans is a nice IDE. I can't really complain. Since I took your class I've been torn between Netbeans and Eclipse, but I think it's fine to use both to take advantage of different plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the JDK & JRE version being used to build the project in NetBeans?

If you are getting problem at compile time, please check your JDK otherwise check your JRE.

If you are using some build tool, check the JDK being used for build tool and `-source` and `-target` for the Java compiler.